# Find all solutions the diophantine equation $x^2+y^2=z^2+w^2+1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, sums-of-squares

> Let $x,y,z,w$ be postive integers,find the diophantine equation all solution
>   $$x^2+y^2=z^2+w^2+1$$

However,  I'm looking for a identity or something like that. Very important is that must be a general solution, it must contain all the odds with all the possible numbers.

Comment: What is the source of this problem?

Comment: Are you familiar with the theory of quadratic forms? You are asking for  all representations of $1$ by the quadratic form $[1,1,-1,-1]$. This form is the sum of two hyperbolic planes (at least I suppose; the integers are not a field so it gets more complicated here...), so there might well be results on how to compute all solutions here.

Comment: @wythagoras,it is test problem

Comment: maybe this $1$ have some special

Comment: Well, it is easy to find some solutions. It is easy to find some parametric forms that produce _infinitely many_ solutions, for example, $\{x,y,z,w\}=\{7k+3,4k+3,k+1,8k+4\}$. But to find _all_ solutions is a problem of entirely different complexity level.

Comment: All decisions are set by the factorization. $$(x-z)(x+z)=ab=w^2-y^2+1$$ $x=\frac{a+b}{2}$ ; $z=\frac{b-a}{2}$

Comment: $$\frac{{{\left( {{s}^{2}}+2s+{{k}^{2}}-{{h}^{2}}+2\right) }^{2}}}{4{{\left( s+1\right) }^{2}}}+{{h}^{2}}=\frac{{{\left( {{s}^{2}}+2s-{{k}^{2}}+{{h}^{2}}\right) }^{2}}}{4{{\left( s+1\right) }^{2}}}+{{k}^{2}}+1$$

Answer (score 4):

Catalan gave the following complete integer solution of the 2.2.3 equation $$X_1^2+X_2^2=Y_1^2+Y_2^2+Y_3^2. \tag{1}$$

> Choose relatively prime integers $\alpha$ and $\beta$, and integers $u$ and $v$ such that $\beta u - \alpha v = 1$. Then all integer solutions of (1) are given, **without repetition**, by the formulas
>   \begin{align*}
>  x_1 &= \tfrac{1}{2}(\alpha^2 + \beta^2 + y_3^2)u + \beta \theta,  &
>   y_1 &= x_1 + \alpha,  \\
>  x_2 &= \tfrac{1}{2}(\alpha^2 + \beta^2 + y_3^2)v + \alpha \theta,  &
>   y_2 &= x_2 - \beta,
> \end{align*}
>   where $\theta$ is an arbitrary integer.

[cf. Dickson’s *History*, Vol II, p. 268; orig: Assoc franç., av. sc. 12, 1883, 98–101]

Your question is one of the special cases $y_1^2=1$ or $y_2^2=1$ or $y_3^2=1$.

Another avenue would be to note that there is a parameterization for every equal sums of squares equation
$$
X_1^2 + \dotsb + X_m^2 = Y_1^2 + \dotsb + Y_n^2
$$
with $n,m$ positive integers and all $X_i,Y_i$ integers; your special case is $(m,n)=(2,3)$, with the addition restriction(s) on the $y_i$. The papers by [Barnett](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2302941?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) and [Bradley](http://www.jstor.org/stable/3620159?origin=JSTOR-pdf&seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) are my first recommendations — they offer parameterizations which you can use as a starting point for your special case(s).

Answer (score 3):

Already the special case $w=0$ has a complicated theory concerning its solutions, see [this MO-question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/114707/the-diophantine-equation-x2-y2-z2-1), involving rational quadratic forms, or an identity
$$
(289p^4+14p^2q^2−239q^4)^2−(17p^2−12pq−13q^2)^4−(17p^2+12pq−13q^2)^4=−1,
$$
with $q^2-17p^2=-1$. So it seems that this is not a reasonable "test problem", to ask for a description of all integral solutions.

Concerning identities we have (as mentioned above)
$$
(7n+3)^2+(4n+3)^2=(n+1)^2+(4(2n+1))^2+1,
$$
which give infinitely many positive integer solutions, but not all.

Comment: Thanks,But $w$ be postive integers

Comment: Could you show us the source of this "test problem"? Or is it from "Art of Problem Solving"?

Comment: There are several elementary ways of characterizing all integral solutions, at least two of which I would describe as “simple”. So as long as this “test” was meant for advanced high school students (or above), I think it’s a totally reasonable problem.

Answer (score 1):

$$x^2+y^2=z^2+w^2+1$$

Write solutions like this.

$$x=\frac{t}{2}((k-p)(k+p+2)+1)+p+1$$

$$y=tk^2-tp(p-1)+2p-1$$

$$z=\frac{t}{2}((k-p)(k+p-2)-1)+p-1$$

$$w=tk(k+1)-tp^2+2p$$

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for $n$ and $n+1$ which are sums of two positive integer
squares. The sums of two integer squares are well-known. They are
the numbers of the form $a^2b$ where $b$ has no prime factors $p$
with $p\equiv3\pmod 4$. If you are strict about positive integers
then you have to eliminate squares $c^2$ where none of $c$'s prime
factors is $\equiv3\pmod 4$. You are then looking for consecutive
numbers of this form. It's difficult to provide a general procedure
for getting these, as the prime factors of $n$ and $n+1$ are "unrelated".

Comment: sorry,I have read your solution,Now I can't understand this idea

Comment: @communnites Here $n$ will be your $z^2+w^2$ and $n+1$ will be your $x^2+y^2$. So we need to find pairs of consecutive numbers that have the form $a^2+b^2$ for positive integers $a$ and $b$. It is well known (due to Fermat) which numbers have that form. It's harder to characterise consecutive pairs with that property.